# Schemaless configuration not writing to index

Tags: indexing, solr

I am somewhat new to Solr and have been trying to follow the example of using the Schemaless configuration. I start up Solr with the following command:

bin/solr start -e schemaless

And solr does start up. I am trying to post an xml document to the schemaless index using the curl command as follows:

curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update?commit=true&wt=xml" -H "Content-type:application/xml" -d "xml text goes here"

However, when I run the curl command to view the fields that should have been added to the index, curl http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema/fields ,  I only see the defaults that existed when first starting up solr.

Is there anything I am missing when starting solr?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is your XML actually formatted like an Solr document, or is it just random XML?

Comment: I am just trying to get the schemaless mode to work correctly using the exact sample in the documentation just running bin/solr start -e schemaless and posting the data using the curl command to port 8983. I have tried to use just xml and I have tried using the json data format, an neither one have worked. I am wondering is there a processor I am missing or a dataImportHandler that needs to be added to the example in the documentation. thanks

Comment: Which of the example content files did you try with? I'm not sure arbitrary XML will work just out of the box.

Comment: I am adding just random XML. After looking at the example it appears that you have to transform your xml to a format that solr wants. ie:

Comment: <add>
<doc>
<field name="element name">GB18030TEST</field>
<field name="element name">Test with some GB18030 encoded characters</field>
<field name="element name">No accents here</field>
<field name="element name">ÕâÊÇÒ»¸ö¹¦ÄÜ</field>
<field name="element name">This is a feature (translated)</field>
<field name="element name">Õâ·ÝÎÄ¼þÊÇºÜÓÐ¹âÔó</field>
<field name="element name">This document is very shiny (translated)</field>
<field name="element name">0.0</field>
<field name="element name">true</field>
</doc>
</add>

Comment: Where the element name is the name of the element in your raw/random xml as well as attributes you want to store.

Comment: Correct - which is why I'm asking :-)